# Allow only subnet routes for a given network interface (Windows)

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet, route

I use a laptop, which has two physical network interfaces: wireless (**IF 11** as printed by route) & Ethernet (**IF 12**). I have two routers **R1** & **R2**, but only the first one does have an internet connection. My goal is to route all traffic via **R1**, but route all requests on a subnet, controlled by **R2** (e.g. `192.168.2.x`) through **R2**.

Windows prefers cable connection over WiFi by default, so I changed the metric for the wireless adapter to be lower then the metric of **IF 12**.

Is there a way do block the OS from creating the default `0.0.0.0`route for the ethernet adapter?

Comment: Just don't add a default gateway in your NIC settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should  be able to accomplish this by not setting a default gateway in the NIC for internal use. If you only set a default gateway on the "Internet" NIC, then you may just need to add a route in Windows with the -p for persistent. You would need to add routes for all networks other than the directly connected subnets.

```
ROUTE -P ADD 10.10.10.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1 METRIC 1
```

Comment: Can I do that (not setting the default gateway) with the `route` command?

Comment: If you put a default gateway in the config, it will make the route in the windows routing table, you could use "route DEL" to remove it, but I am not sure if you can make that survive a reboot.